# Encryption and Decryption in Python with Text&Key as arguments

Tags: python, function, encryption, key

I am working on a code where I have to encrypt & decrypt a simple text. I have the idea for the flow of the code, but I am missing on which types etc. are working the best. 
Is there for example a way to have an empty dictionary with key a - z and then add those argument values ?

I was also given 2 functions that should help but I am not sure on how to use them.

```
def print_cipher(key):
    for i in range(len(key)):
        print(f'{alphabet[i]} - {key[i]}')


def shuffle_letters(letters):
    scrambled = list(letters)
    shuffle(scrambled)
    return ''.join(scrambled)
```

Thanks and looking forward to helping hands!

Comment: Just a warning because it caught me by surprise: `print(f'{alphabet[i]} - {key[i]}')` uses a [string interpolation feature](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) that was introduced in python 3.6

Comment: If you have an idea for the flow, maybe write it down in plain English and include that in your question.  That is a good place to start.